# How to delete a File from S3 after it is loaded

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a STAGE and PIPE setup to load data from a S3 folder to a SNOWFLAKE table.
I have setup event notifications to load the file as and when it is uploaded to S3.

It is all working fine.

I want to delete the file in the S3 folder after it is loaded.

How do I Accomplish that.

I tried this statement and it does not seem to work

alter table nph_contact set stage_copy_options = (purge = true);

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi Purge = TRUE should be deleting the files , please check the user id that you are using to COPY into the stage has the required permission in the folders inside the S3 bucket.

Comment: According to Snowflake Support the PURGE is misleading. It will only work if the files are copied using COPY INTO via a Task. I am using SNOWPIPE so the PURGE won't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the recommendations in the documentation for the [PURGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html) option:

> We recommend that you list staged files periodically (using LIST) and
> manually remove successfully loaded files, if any exist.

A better way would be to do a process in which, after making sure the data is loaded correctly, you use the [REMOVE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/remove.html) function.

Example:

```sql
remove @mystage/path1/subpath2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Question. How do I make sure the files are loaded? I can use the COPY_HISTORY to see the files that were loaded so maybe I can use that. Let me know if there are other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

add purge = TRUE in your copy command script